# Cannot check retention policy on this site

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, document, retention

I have a document library in SharePoint 2016 in which I added Retention policy for document deletion , But still I  am getting Yellow striped Error"Cannot check retention policy on this site". Please Help me out.

Answer (score 0):

This notification can be caused by the new feature “Site-Based Retention Policies” which was published this [October, 2014](https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/206884).

Based on my testing, it is harmless and can be safely ignored. As per Microsoft, Timer Job for executing Information Policy on weekly basis. Wait for few days and check you defined action has been executed as per defined policy.

Let me know if any concern.

If you found this answer solved your issue, please mark it as right answer.

Thanks & Regards.